# Placing data in MySQL database from form fields created on the fly

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form that allows members to click a (+) sign, and it will put another form field there. They can do this to basically without limit.

The problem I have is if they do it, let's say, 3 times and fill out all 3, when I get the data to save it, it's placing the first field in the database and not the others.

Here is my code:

Here is the JavaScript that makes the div show as they push the (+) sign.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function add_feed()
{
    var div1 = document.createElement('div');
    div1.innerHTML = document.getElementById('newlinktpl').innerHTML;
    document.getElementById('newlink').appendChild(div1);
}
</script>
<style>
   .feed {padding: 5px 0}
</style>
```

This is part of the form that does the above...

```
<td width="50%" valign="top">
<div id="newlink">
<div class="feed">
<input type="text" size="45" value="" name="recname[]" placeholder="Place Company Name Here"><br /><br />
<input type="text" size="45" value="" name="reclink[]" placeholder="Place URL Here"><br /><br />
<p><b>What Type Of Page Is This?</b><br /><br />
<input type="radio" name="rectype[]" value="1"> Business Opp<br />
<input type="radio" name="rectype[]" value="2"> Traffic Site<br />
<input type="radio" name="rectype[]" value="3"> Tools Site<br /></p>
</div>
</div>
<hr>
<p id="addnew">
<a href="javascript:add_feed()">+ Click Here To Add Another Biz/Traffic/Tools Site</a>
</p>
<div id="newlinktpl" style="display:none">
<hr>
<div class="feed">
<input type="text" size="45" value="" name="recname[]" placeholder="Place Company Name Here"><br /><br />
<input type="text" size="45" value="" name="reclink[]" placeholder="Place URL Here"><br /><br />
<p><b>What Type Of Page Is This?</b><br /><br />
<input type="radio" name="rectype[]" value="1"> Business Opp<br />
<input type="radio" name="rectype[]" value="2"> Traffic Site<br />
<input type="radio" name="rectype[]" value="3"> Tools Site<br /></p>
</div>
</div>
```

This is the part of the PHP code that would save it...

```
$i=0;
$linkname = $_POST["recname"][0];
while($linkname != ""){
$linkname = $_POST["recname"][$i];
$linkurl = $_POST["reclink"][$i];
$linktype = $_POST["rectype"][$i];
$linkname = $res->real_escape_string($linkname);
$linkurl = $res->real_escape_string($linkurl);
$linktype = $res->real_escape_string($linktype);
$result299 = mysqli_query($res, "INSERT INTO user_links (linkname,linkurl,linktype,sort) VALUES ('$linkname','$linkurl','$linktype','0')");
$i++;
}
```

It's all working except that is does not store all the data in the database (only the first one saves). That's the part I need help with please.

Please explain what I have done wrong and how to get it to store all the fields in the database, no matter how many the user creates and fills out.

Comment: Looks like it the frontend part should work, the PHP part is a bit weird though. You will want to put the recname (and reclink, rectype...) in `$_POST["recname"]` in quotes, otherwise it will be seen as a bareword. Stuff like that only "cleanly" works in Perl... You should enable notices as you would have seen a notice like "Use of undefined constant recname - assumed 'recname'"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested your code and it works fine so far if I use it like this:

```
  $i=0;
  $linkname = $_POST[recname][0];
  while($linkname != ""){
    $linkname = $_POST[recname][$i];
    $linkurl = $_POST[reclink][$i];
    $linktype = $_POST[rectype][$i];
    echo "INSERT INTO user_links (linkname,linkurl,linktype,sort) VALUES ('$linkname','$linkurl','$linktype','0')<br>\n";
    $i++;
  }
```

There's no information about the $res object you're calling real_escape_string() on, so I'll just skip that for now. There are a couple of weaknesses in the code though:

### You are referencing the post keys with barenames instead of strings.

PHP will gracefully assume you meant it as a string, but it will trigger a notice like `Use of undefined constant recname - assumed 'recname'`. Enclose them in quotes to make it clean.

### Your use of the loop will result in an empty element inserted in the database every time.

You set the new linkname AFTER checking if $linkname is empty, but the variable contains the name of the last iteration. Instead, do something like this:

```
$i=0;
while($linkname = $_POST["recname"][$i]){
    $linkurl = $_POST["reclink"][$i];
    $linktype = $_POST["rectype"][$i];
    echo "INSERT INTO user_links (linkname,linkurl,linktype,sort) VALUES ('$linkname','$linkurl','$linktype','0')<br>\n";
    $i++;
}
```

### Your code only allows for one radio button to be checked at a time

You cannot use `rectype[]` as a name for radio buttons, as an equal name forms a group of radio buttons out of all the elements. You need to name them like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="rectype[0]" value="1"> Business Opp<br />
<input type="radio" name="rectype[0]" value="2"> Traffic Site<br />
<input type="radio" name="rectype[0]" value="3"> Tools Site<br />

<input type="radio" name="rectype[1]" value="1"> Business Opp<br />
<input type="radio" name="rectype[1]" value="2"> Traffic Site<br />
<input type="radio" name="rectype[1]" value="3"> Tools Site<br />
```

and so on. You can do that programatically in your javascript code like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var counter = 1;

function add_feed()
{
    var div1 = document.createElement('div');
    div1.innerHTML = document.getElementById('newlinktpl').innerHTML;
    var inputs = div1.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (i=0; i<inputs.length; i++) {
      if (inputs[i].type == "radio") {
        inputs[i].name="rectype[" + counter + "]";
      }
    }
    counter++;
    document.getElementById('newlink').appendChild(div1);
}
</script>
```

That said, I don't see why it should only save one item, unless you have a key constraint hitting or something else we cannot assume from the piece of code you shared.

Comment: OK, I changed the name for the two different radio sets and now it will save the first 2 complete sets of data but if I press the + button again and create a 3rd or more sets of data, it only saves the first 2 sets. So now at least I know it has something to do with one being [0] and the other being [1]. So in the javascript should I add something that will fill in that field with 0 then 1 then 2 then 3 and so on? If so what would I add to it?

Comment: You need to programatically set the name of the radio inputs. The third input should have a name of `rectype[2]`, not `rectype[1]`, so if you just changed the template code to `rectype[1]` you will only get two types submitted of course. I will add some javascript to my answer to make clear how.

Comment: I added a working example for the required javascript part. The global `counter` variable keeps track of the number to insert in this case.

Comment: That works perfect, thank you so much for your help!